# Not able to view uploaded doc in Google Drive using drive SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have a simple program that inserts doc in Google Drive using drive SDK. I am using a service account:

```
try {
    credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("1090759145727-abc@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
                    .setServiceAccountUser("1090759145727-abc@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                            new java.io.File(url.getPath())).build();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                                 .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                                 .setApplicationName("guestbook").build();

File body = new File();
body.setTitle("Test document");
body.setDescription("Test file descrition");
body.setMimeType("text/html");

java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("index.html");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/html", fileContent);

File file = driveService.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

Using the above code `index.html` file is inserted to drive. I was able to confirm by logging the `fileId` from `file` object. But, I am not able to view the file in my google drive account.

If I share the file using my gmail ID, I am able to view it in my drive account.

```
Permission permission = new Permission();
permission.setId("xyz@gmail.com");
permission.setType("user");
permission.setRole("writer");
Insert insert = driveService.permissions().insert(file.getId(), permission);
insert.execute();
```

I am also not able to get the export links `Map`. The export links map in `null`.

```
Map<String, String> links = file.getExportLinks();
```

When service accounts are used:

- where to the files get stored?
- How can I view the files?
- How can I retrieve the export links?

Comment: Can you find the file in drive when you search for it? If the file is successfully uploaded but does not show up in the drive ui it is probably because your file is not assigned to a root folder. You can get the rootFolderId via the about method (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) and assign your file the root folder as a parent folder.

Comment: Export links are only available for Google Docs, since you upload an html file there will be no export links. (see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files)

Comment: @konqi - Thank you for the help. I am now able to retrieve the export links. But, when I use the link to download it asks the user to request for permission to download file. Then it says an email will be sent to the owner to approve the request. But, I did not get any email ?

Comment: @konqi - I assigned a root folder ID as parent to the file that I created, but I am still not able to view the file in the drive UI. I am accessing my personal gmail account to view the files. Is it the right place or is there a separate drive for the service account?

Comment: In your credential builder you need to change `.setServiceAccountUser(<email>)` to your email account.

Comment: When I add `setServiceAccountUser ` I am getting `TokenResponseException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

Comment: Obviously you would need to configure domain wide delegation on your google apps domain for that. To access the drive of a non-apps gmail user you need to request offline access to the users drive via oauth.